# Determination of number of subjects for repeated measures experiments

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, p-value, sample-size

I am recording the joystick commands of human subjects for a tracking task. I record 16 such data for each human subject. The task is same for all the trials. I was wondering how I can determine how many human subjects I need for statistical significance? And will it be possible to do t-test to determine p-value?